# How to handle raw data where a column may contain more than 1 entry per row?

Tags: excel, csv, collections, multiple-columns

I have some data I would like to export (happens to be from Ruby, but that's unimportant) into a generic format for further analysis. Unfortunately, some records/lines/data entries may contain greater than 1 value (or 0, for that matter) for a given column.

For example, a person may be wearing sunglasses AND a hat. There are multiple columns like this.

I'm not sure how to handle collections of data that ideally could fall under the same column in a generic format (I need to import this data into other software, ideally including Excel).

The only simple, generic method I can think of is to have a column for each potential piece of data and treat it as a boolean. But I'd rather not, since then I would end up with over 300 columns. And then I'd also have to include a secondary CSV file that specified which columns belong to which categories.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output that data to a csv file, you could group the data into one field using a different separator:

```
John,sunglasses|hat,other,fields
```

Or using the same separator, but then the field needs to be quoted (and quotes already inside the field would need to be escaped with another quote):

```
John,"sunglasses,hat",other,fields
```

Or, if the number of other fields is not large, you could use a row for each value:

```
John,sunglasses
John,hat
```

Or you could use xml:

```
<record>
    <name>John</name>
    <options>
        <option>sunglasses</option>
        <option>hat</option>
    </options>
</record>
```

It all depends on how you want to process the exported data.